How do I obtain the file path of an imported react functional component?
I'm trying to add SSR to a routing module I'm working on in Bun.
I'd like the code to look something like this:
import Index from "./app/client/pages/Index";
import About from "./app/client/pages/About";
import { route, page } from "mypackage";

route.get("/", (context) => {
  return page.render(<Index />);
});

route.get("/about/:name", (context) => {
  return page.render(<About name={context.groups.name} />);
});

In the page render function, I need to get the actual path to the react elements that were imported so that I can use Bun.build to convert them to js, and also to hydrate them on the client side.
I cannot figure out how to get the path from the react element.
Here is what I've tried.
page render:
export const render = (child: React.FC) => {
  console.log(child);

  console.log(require.resolve(child));

  console.log(require.resolve(typeof child));
}

terminal output:
{
  $$typeof: Symbol(react.transitional.element),
  type: [Function: starDefault],
  key: null,
  props: {},
  _owner: null,
  ref: null,
  _store: {
    validated: 0,
  },
  _debugInfo: null,
}

error: Cannot find package "[object Object]" from "/Users/kejedi/Bun/framework/test.tsx"

Is this possible, or am I going to have to resolve it another way?

Bun converts JSX into JS automatically, is this some kind of extra functionality you're using on top of it?

@Derek I know but that's only for server-side. In order to hydrate the react component I need to build the tsx file into js, and then hydrate it. So I need to know the path of the component that is passed through page.render.
